# Polarization on a spherical electromagnetic wave in free space using classical electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, polarization

The polarization of a plane wave traveling in free space is well defined and traverse to the direction of propagation from classical electromagnetic theory.
Spherical waves are another type of frequently used solutions. However, I am finding it difficult to visualize how are the polarization vectors arranged over the spherical wavefront, referring to the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: If memory serves, there's a comment in Zangwill about this very subject.  I'll try to remember to look it up when I'm in my office on Monday.

Comment: Zangwill's discussion is in Section 16.8.  I may write a summary at some point, but it'll require some thought before I can do so.  In the meantime, check out [Transverse wave vs the hairy-ball theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366214), [How do you make a spherical radio wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251971/), and [How do coherent isotropic radiators evade the hairy-ball theorem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311859/)

Answer (score 2):

A realistic antenna is a dipole. The dipole radiation has no field in the directions you would expect singularities from the hairy ball theorem.